# Различие методов getActiveCount() и getTaskCount() ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, многопоточность

В чём заключается различие методов `getActiveCount()` и `getTaskCount()` класса `ThreadPoolExecutor`? Правильно, я понимаю, что `getActiveCount()` - это приблизительное количество потоков, которые выполняют задания, а `getTaskCount()` - приблизительное общее количество задач, которые когда-либо были запланированы для выполнения. Т.е., правильно ли я понимаю, что значение, возвращаемое вторым методом, включает и выполняющиеся в данный момент задания, и уже выполненные и завершённые задания?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что мешает проверить?

```
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
    import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
    import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    public class ThreadPoolExecutorTest {
        private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ThreadPoolExecutorTest.class.getName());

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            BlockingQueue<Runnable> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(100);


            ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                10, 20, 1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS, blockingQueue
            );

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                threadPoolExecutor.execute(new TestRunnable());

                System.out.println("ActiveCount:" + threadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount());
                System.out.println("TaskCount: " + threadPoolExecutor.getTaskCount());
            }
        }
    }

    class TestRunnable implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(10000) + 2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

По выводу видно:

```
ActiveCount:1
TaskCount: 1
ActiveCount:2
TaskCount: 2
ActiveCount:3
TaskCount: 3
ActiveCount:4
TaskCount: 4
ActiveCount:5
TaskCount: 5
ActiveCount:6
TaskCount: 6
ActiveCount:7
TaskCount: 7
ActiveCount:8
TaskCount: 8
ActiveCount:9
TaskCount: 9
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 10
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 11
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 12
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 13
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 14
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 15
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 16
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 17
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 18
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 19
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 20
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 21
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 22
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 23
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 24
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 25
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 26
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 27
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 28
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 29
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 30
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 31
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 32
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 33
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 34
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 35
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 36
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 37
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 38
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 39
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 40
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 41
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 42
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 43
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 44
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 45
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 46
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 47
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 48
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 49
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 50
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 51
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 52
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 53
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 54
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 55
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 56
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 57
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 58
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 59
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 60
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 61
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 62
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 63
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 64
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 65
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 66
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 67
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 68
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 69
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 70
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 71
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 72
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 73
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 74
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 75
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 76
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 77
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 78
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 79
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 80
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 81
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 82
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 83
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 84
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 85
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 86
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 87
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 88
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 89
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 90
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 91
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 92
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 93
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 94
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 95
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 96
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 97
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 98
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 99
ActiveCount:10
TaskCount: 100
```

что getActiveCount - это количество запущенное сейчас, а getTaskCount - запущенные когда либо.